# switch back to the running flutter app from another app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, kotlin, dart

I want to switch from flutter app to phone dialer, do a call, and after call, I want to switch back to the flutter app. Someone guide me how to do it.

Comment: You can't on iOS.  The user will need to take an action to switch back to your app; switching to your app, tapping its icon or tapping a notification from your app

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about calling from the app then you can use the url launcher package from pub.dev - and add this

```
tel:<phone number>
```

Here is the [package](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) link

Comment: I know about that; I also want to come back from that application.